# OpenGL 2D modelToWorld matrix not working

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I'm currently writing some routine to display a 2D tilemap.
The vertex shader looks like:

```
#version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 vTexCoord;

out vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 modelToWorld;
uniform mat4 worldToView;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = worldToView * modelToWorld * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
  texCoord = vTexCoord;
}
```

Then I wrote a batch renderer for the painting method.
It works fine.
However, I decided to center the (square) tilemap in the screen by providing a translation matrix to the uniform `worldToView` . 
But unfortunatly it does not work, the tilemap is still displayed from topleft corner.

Any idea of what's wrong ?

Comment: The shader looks fine, are you sure that the matrices you're sending to the shader are correct?

Comment: More to the point, are the matrices transposed from what OpenGL expects?